# What choice of parameters makes this function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Given constants $\alpha, \beta > 0$ define $$ f_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = x^{\alpha} \sin(x^{\beta})$$ for $x > 0$.

For which pairs $\alpha, \beta$ is $f_{\alpha, \beta}$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708762/when-is-x-alpha-sinx-beta-uniformly-continuous-for-alpha-beta-0

Comment: On what domain is uniform continuity supposed to hold (or not)?